# what is the easiest way to set a default choice for a django select widget?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model that has a foreign key relation to another.  I'd like to have the dropdown that is produced by widget=forms.Select have a default value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe just create a form and set the field's initial value:

```
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ('field',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['field'].initial = 'initial value'
```